# I have an existing program, but would like to deploy it as brand new. How can do this?

Tags: program

My program is in development but has been deployed to devnet. I have made changes and would like to deploy it as a new program.

I'm able to create a new wallet json file and update the program to have the new program id. It builds and deploys successfully, but when I run code to access the program I get error 0xbbb.

I am using anchor and I've updated my Anchor.toml file with the new program id and the declare_id as well.

Comment: I just tried getting rid of my original program's id.json file and created a new one and deployed. The deploy worked but running client code still gives the error 0xbbb

Comment: Which anchor version are you using ? 0xbbb = 3003 which means Failed to deserialize the account according to latest version but if you are using old version that may be user generated error.